# Why is a stopped BehaviorSubject halting execution in a pipe of RXJS?

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code:

```js
this.workingStore$.pipe(
  filter((workingStores) => !!workingStores[docID]),
  concatMap((workingStores) => {
    console.log(
      'returning from concatMap',
      workingStores[docID].getInitialDataSet(),
    );
    return workingStores[docID].getInitialDataSet();
  }),
  filter((isSet) => {
    console.log('looking for set', isSet);
    return isSet;
  }),
),
```

`workingStores[docID].getInitialDataSet()` returns an Observable. Because the pipes that set it to `true` complete, the `BehaviorSubject` gets `isStopped: true` internally. Once it becomes `true`, the `filter` no longer fires for `isSet`.

Shouldn't it just know to return the final value? It seems that's not the case so how would I wrote this so the last `filter` always runs? If I do the following, it works, but is awfully code smelly

```js
concatMap((workingStores) => {
  if (
    workingStores[docID].getInitialDataSet().getValue() === true
  ) {
    return of(true);
  }
  return workingStores[docID].getInitialDataSet();
}),
```

I am aware `ReplaySubject` will give values, even after stopped, but I don't want to emit old values to any subscriber.

Comment: Could you mock up this code as a stackblitz so we can better see what may be happening here?

Comment: My first guess would be to try AsyncSubject. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/asyncsubject . I remember that has to do with something after isStopped: true

Comment: Does getInitialDataset() return an observable?

Comment: @adam yes it is a stopped one.

Answer (score 0):

`ReplaySubject` has a constructor that accepts the number of latest events to replay. If you provide 1 it will act similarly to your `BehaviorSubject`.